# Are you ready to meet the Elite-Four?

Tags: code-golf

To be able to challenge the Elite-4 of top programmers, you need to show your badges first, that qualify you as a potential programmer-master. However, there's a twist. Once you show a badge, it is collected, which means you can't re-show it. So better come prepared! There are `n` badge collectors, each has a known list of `accepted_badges`. Given a list of your `badges`, your task is to find out, if you can access elite-four or if you require more badges. You can indicate this by printing a truthy-value for the first case or a falsey-value in the second case.

**Example**

```
accepted_badges: [ [a, b, c], [a, b, d], [d, e, f]]
```

If you have the badges `[a, b, d]`  you can pass. Simply give your `a` badge to the first collector (`accepted_badges[0]`), your `b` badge to the second and your d badge to the last collector. So this is a truthy case.

If you have the badges `[a, b, c]` you are in bad luck. The last collector doesn't accept any of it.

If you have the badges `[b, c, d]` you can also pass. Here  you will need to give your `c` badge to the first collector, the `b` badge to the second and the final collector will get the `d` badge.

If you have the badges `[a, e, f]` you will not be admitted, because you would have to use your a badge twice (since the first collector takes it away from you), which is not possible.

**Input:**

> A list* of your badges
>   A 2Dlist* of badge collectors and their accepted badges

*list can be the following:

```
1. a list, i.e. [a, b, c, ...] or [[a,b,c],[c,d,e]]
2. a list with first element = number of elements i.e. [3, a, b, c] or [ [2], [3, a, b, c], [1, a]]
2. a string     "abcd..."  
3. a string with leading number of elements i.e. "3abc"  
4. a seperated string i.e. "abc,def,ghi"
5. a separated string with leading numbers of elements i.e. "3abc,2ab,5abcdef"
6. or any other convenient input format you can think of
```

**Assumptions:**

You may assume:

- any list to never be empty
- input letters to always match `[a-z]`
- your number of badges matches the number of badge collectors

You may not assume:

- that any list is sorted

**Test cases (list format):**

```
['a','b','c','d']
[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['b','c','d'], ['c', 'g']]
Truthy

['a', 'a', 'a']  
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f']]
Truthy

['a', 'a', 'f']
[['a', 'c', 'f'], ['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c']]
Falsey

['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
[['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y'], ['z', 'w'], ['x', 'y']]
Falsey

['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']
[['p', 'q', 'r'], ['r', 'q', 'p'], ['r'], ['s', 't'], ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']]
Truthy

['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']
[['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'], ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'], ['p', 'q', 'r'], ['p', 'q'], ['p']]
Truthy
```

**Test cases (String format):**

```
"abcd"
"abc def bcd cg"
Truthy

"aaa"  
"abc ade abef"
Truthy

"aaf"
"acf ad bc"
Falsey

"xyzw"
"xy xy zw xy"
Falsey

"pqrst"
"pqr rqp r st pqrst"
Truthy

"pqrst"
"pqrst pqrs pqr pq p"
Truthy
```

Lastly, this is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf) so the answer with the least number of bytes wins. Please refrain from using any standard-loopholes.

Comment: Would've been nice if the list items in the test cases were already strings....

Comment: Added string formatted testcases

Comment: Thanks but I meant for them to be quoted :) That way I could copy&paste into the code without having to do much input formatting; these new strings still don't solve my problem :(

Comment: Oh of course. Will keep that in mind for future challenges.

Comment: Your first test case has 1 too many badges or 1 too few badge checkers.

Comment: Whoops, fixed it.

Comment: I suggest adding the case `[a, e, f]` to the example, so it will cover all of the rules.

Comment: @Nitrodon with what accepted badges?

Comment: I mean the worked example at the top, with the same accepted badges `[ [a, b, c], [a, b, d], [d, e, f]]`.

Comment: I think this is already covered by the 3rd test case. What is different?

Comment: It's covered by the fourth test case (not the third), but not by the worked example.

Comment: I'm not sure allowing `6.` as input is a good idea. Somebody is bound to abuse it.

Comment: @infinitezero Is this the entrance contest for Elite-Four? It seems to be really hard to solve...

Comment: @infinitezero: The `[a, e, f]` example that Nitrodon is suggesting fails, even though you have a matching badge for every collector, because you can't use your `a` badge twice (for the first two collectors, who don't accept `e` or `f`). This is covered in the test cases but it is missing from the more verbose explanation where you list and explain three examples. I suggest appending this as a fourth explanation to ensure that the explanation contains all of the requirements.

Comment: Added the example.

Comment: ```return "no"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
.»â€˜JIå
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79Duw4seNa05PcfL8/DS//@jlSoqlXQUoGRVOZQdy1VRWVUOAA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

One of the few cases where itertools is useful.

```python
lambda b,a:s(b)in map(s,product(*a))
s=sorted
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY7BDoMgDIbvPgU3cPG04xKfxHkAlc1EhQHL5l7eWURXNV52@Wm@0q/Vvbur7jzI9Do0vBUlJyLhF8tEXHek5ZrZRBtVPgvHTjyOI5taZVxVRtKoltSuMk6pxpK61SM/DdrUnSOSZZTThFABUUCUNE9ItsZAxsZYVxByAtuZqb7RPI@jjT7EgZlPDq//AYH3HSglVhboNo7OmletHG@APcQH4hVEAfs5XKNPC1/5NMAHhIGwEC5Icc8bzAL0DPyDpo6Efy1d9/atHcUg1OPm4Qs)

Comment: Why do you have `f=\` in some separate header?

Comment: To call a lambda function, we have to assign a name to it. However in CGCC, we apparently don't need to include the `f=`. The only time you need to specify its name is in a recursive call.

Comment: You know that there's a [bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5603/92069) for this?

Comment: Yes, I am in fact aware of that bounty. Unfortunately, it expired long ago, so I doubt that I'm eligible for it.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,l:l and any(f(s.replace(x,'',1),l[1:])for x in l[0])or''==s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZA9DoMwDIV3TuHNIEVV6YiUk6AMgSQtUhpCEqnQy9P8oNKhg/2e7M8ent3CYza3fVdU8@cgOHiiOw3ciFhbrWp/cdJqPsp6JYikbYju2441anawwmRA91fWzA6RUr8H6YMHCn0F0CMfRoGkmKgopEpSpjjekTFSQM5/OS5kliHyEYGDUYUZVWHKqxNYt/crE@uWVqXnUfJfzC7Oh8xFl5ZusVlSy5sD@X9xEocWyT2eVKyqUjSegE7p5EC6@Ma6yQSIeRLd7B8)

Tries every possible character from each list entry in turn, removing it from the target string `s` if present, and checking if we end up with the empty string. The `s.replace(x,'',1)` removes at most one copy of `x` in the string `s`.

An annoying issue is that in the base case where `l==[]`, we get an error when we try to read `l[0]` even if the result doesn't matter, making it hard to cut the `l and`. It "almost" works to save a byte as below, but we get an error when `l` becomes empty because the `l[0]` is evaluated before the `if l` is tested and fails.

```python
f=lambda s,l:s==''or any(f(s.replace(x,'',1),l[1:])for x in l[0]if l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZCxDoMwDER3vsKbQYqq0hGJL0EZAiQtUgohiVTSn6dOgkqHLr6T79nDmeAfy3zbd9Vq8exHAY7pxrUt4mJBzKFUpbtYabQYZLkxRFZXTHd1wytFxAbTDLq78kmBrnYvnXfQQlcAdCj6YUSWDSmOUkXJWxzuyDnLoBC/nBhlkp54QuBgVGYGlZn86gS28H4lYgsxyjOtov9iZrXOJ45cDO1qksSRkgP5f3ESh2ZJk04KXhSxF8dAx2pSIQ29MXaaPVCZjGr6AA)

**69 bytes**

```python
f=lambda s,l:any(f(s.replace(x,'',1),l[1:]+[[]])for x in l[0])or''==s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNDoIwEITvfYq9LcTGiEcSnqTpoUCrJBVq20Tw5Wt/iHjwsjPZ@XYPYzZ/X@ZrCKrT4tGPAhzVrZi3SlXubKXRYpDVShFpU1PNmpafGOO8VouFFaYZNLvwerGIXeeCl8476IARAIaiH0akxUTFUaokZYvDDTmnBRTilxOjzNJHPiKwM6owgypMeXUA6/Z@ZWLdUlRmXiX/xczTOp@56FJonyZLGjnZkf8XB7FrkTzjCeGEpGocBZ3ayYW08Y2x0@whlkp1HT4)

Pad `l` to the right with empty lists.

**69 bytes**

```python
f=lambda s,h,*t:t and any(f(s.replace(x,'',1),*t)for x in h)or s in h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBjsIwDEX3PYV3aZCFxCyROAnqwm0SWimUkESinct3HKcaWLCw/5f97MUPax4f88@2uYune28IEo54yOcMNBuutXVtOkYbPA22XVApPGkGtHtEWGCaYdTskrgt25QTXODaAFwV9YNRWA2rMtYVqVM13FTXYQWJPjkyVqRnnhHYGVeZwVWmvnoDy/r7EmJZy6p2GRX/j4VnTFk4dmUZn0GkNNnsyPeLN7FrFel80nRNU5JJCL5EIoGc@U2I05yBs8TDnULrp5TRa739AQ)

Takes input as the target string, followed by a splatted list of lists.

---

### 69 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,l:any(f(s.replace(x,'',1),l[x in l[0]:])for x in s)or[]==l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNDsIgEIX3PcXsaBNi1GWTnoSwoC1oE2wRSAQvjzA01oWb9@bnm1k8E/19W68pqUGLxzgLcFT3Yo2tat3JSqPFJNtACaGXjmoWYFlBszPveac2C9i7brOMD4NOXjrvYADWADAixmkmtBbZySxVsTol041wTisoxC8nZok2Zj4jsDOqMpOqTH11ACG@X0iEWFZVcVTqL2ae1nnkclWW9mnQiuBmR/5fHMTu1VDzScObpuTiKOgSDQbS5zfGLquHHCrVXfoA)

A "dual" method based on [ovs' solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203503/20260), iterating over characters in the target string and removing from the list.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 54 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
(.permutations).any.flip elem.mapM id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzyezuIQrzVZDryC1KLe0JLEkMz@vWFMvMa9SLy0ns0AhNSc1Vy83scBXITPlf25iZp5tQVFmXolKWnS0kY6hjkGsTrSxjqWOEYiOjQWygaKx/wE)

## Without imports, 85 bytes

```hs
x#[]=[[x]]
x#(a:b)=(x:a:b):map(a:)(x#b)
(.foldr((=<<).(#))[[]]).any.flip elem.mapM id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsMgEADveUXAHnZBpE1PlfiEvmDZgyFKpWol6cG83pjTDAPzsfvXxdhaFcSGqDIPVYDVCxqo@qJOtvSAUMWCgzeg/C@uG4CZZ1QgEImYUdl8KB9DGV10SfXpPYa1JRuyKVvI/5snmuRD3lnSU77kdJG5e6/cTg)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 79 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:a==[]or any(f(a[x in a[0]:],b[:i]+b[i+1:])for i,x in enumerate(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZCxbsMwDER3fwU32bCGpqMAf4mggbSlVECjOLKC2vl5R6KMukMX3oH3yOHmLX3dw@e@u@EbbzQhoCSFw6DNPQKGrXUt6hV8ANQfRhlJWnnTk/b9RZnOZcpLzm143mzEZFvquj3ZJS0wgG4AtEAaJyGrySom64rUrRivwhhZQcS/HE6WhTKfETgYV5nRVaa@OoF1e/0wsW4lqpNXxf9i8yMuibnsShgfM0sZnBzI/xcncWgVnvmkMU1T2iEJWOrhQlR@M0cfEuRaJXX7Gw)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

```
œεøε`¢]PZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORzWw/vOLc14dCi2ICo///T0pK4opUSk5KVdBSUElNSwVRSappSLAA)

Comment: Can't really think of a better method either thus far. But you can save a byte by changing the `}P}Z` to `]PZ`: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6ORzWw/vOLc14dCi2ICo///TUpK4opUSk5KVdBSUElNSwVRSappSLAA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>66</s> 65 bytes

Port of my Python answer.

-1 byte thanks to @AdHocGarfHunter.

```hs
b#(a:s)=or[x!b#s|x<-a,elem x b]
b#x=1>0
x!(a:b)|a==x=b|w<-x!b=a:w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hczBCsIwDAbg@57it/Wg4ECvYn0R8ZCunYrTzXbQbuzda5QdNi9CEviTj1zJ321VpaTlivZ@rWp3igst/RAPOW1sZR@I0OdMy6h2x20WF@z0eiClotJDOOTMFe1DetDtCQVTZ0Djbs8WSwjShRGQCLUz/hthbAneoriImST6gWQsSNtSYO7KqStKdvxvjmLXh4mKHbj6wHPumpfz7QRyhns1cPAtxuMfP8LP4EYj0hs)

Comment: `,` is shorter than `&&` by a byte.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter this fails with `parse error on input ‘|’`. I think replacing `&&` with `,` only works in guards?

Comment: [?](https://tio.run/##hczBCsIwDAbg@57it/Wg4ECvYn0R8ZCunYrTzXbQbuzda5QdNi9CEviTj1zJ321VpaTlivZ@rWp3igst/RAPOW1sZR@I0OdMy6h2x20WF@z0eiClotJDOOTMFe1DetDtCQVTZ0Djbs8WSwjShRGQCLUz/hthbAneoriImST6gWQsSNtSYO7KqStKdvxvjmLXh4mKHbj6wHPumpfz7QRyhns1cPAtxuMfP8LP4EYj0hs "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter thanks for helping me out. I was literally replacing `&&` with `,`, which obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 138 bytes

Aaargh! Erlang's cartesian product is eeeeevil! (It saved 20 bytes anyway.)

```erlang
f(A,B)->lists:member(lists:sort(A),[lists:sort(tuple_to_list(C))||C<-sofs:to_external(sofs:product(list_to_tuple([sofs:set(I)||I<-B])))]).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDbisIwEIbvfQrJ1QRSH6CIoF75DEVKmkwk0JNJxCq@e52Jy66woIH8mflnvpwwtLo/FRhN8GOaF7ODrdrJYtP6mGLZYddggFcSh5BgK1X1lqbL2GKdhpo92Ev5eOzXRRxcLMnEKWHodQvZGMNgLybl3RjJLFS5FjHBgeDDutgdpZRHuZo77Xuo5bLYLJY0/FBeg08IDoRujBWq4lUoYdGRZkuYkyBeUXPfglT/Sa3/QG2RtSH@C@QyZFyG8mGfiel2vzIy3ag5C@ccfcTGc4iJOQqoPZxHVprs5uqXi/Kzfl/X2J/PeWNW8xM)

## Explanation

Here `...` stands for nest the previous line inside this position.

````erlang
f(A,B)-> % Take 2 items.
[sofs:set(I)||I<-B] % Convert every item of B into a sofs set

list_to_tuple(...) % Convert the input list into a tuple

sofs:product(...)  % Cartesian product of this set tuple

sofs:to_external(...) % Pick the value of the cartesian product

C<-...            % Assign it to the variable C

[lists:sort(tuple_to_list(C))||...] % For every item, convert the tuple to a list
                                    % And then sort that list

lists:member(lists:sort(A),...).    % Is argument 1 a member of the processed list?
```
````

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>170</strike> 168 bytes

*Edited: Switched to returning 1 from inner `main` calls to save a byte not needing to negate the return value when assigning into `u`. Also another byte saved thanks to @ceilingcat for reminding me about `index` instead of `strchr`.*

```c
f;char*l,*u;main(n,x)char**x;{if(f++){if(n){for(int i=0;l[i];i++)if(u[i]&&index(*x,l[i])){u[i]=0;u[i]=main(n-1,x+1);}return 1;}exit(1);}u=strdup(l=x[1]);main(n-2,x+2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LCsMgEEV/JaugxkDNVvIlIQvjox1IbbEKAyHfPtW0q3s5Z2YYO96tJQraPkwSuxRFPw1EFiXyCwnUBwQWhoG3jPwIr8Qg5g7mm94XWDVUV1Wpve8hOo9MoGyK86PROnjF7/KoJA6K6zP5XFLslD49QmYNlfmTkytvts@4qJX/nxmnujJVT0Rms46MJecDtfYF)

A relatively straightforward recursive backtracking search. Takes input as command-line arguments, the first being the list of badges you have in a single character string (e.g. `abcd`) and each other argument being the list of badges accepted by each station in similar format. Contrary to traditional exit code logic the program's exit code is 0 when you cannot pass and 1 when you can pass, mainly because the return value of `main` is used in the program and it works out better that way. There is no output on stdout.

Originally I'd written a subroutine for the search part after initializing some state in `main` but when I abstracted the globals and saw the function signature was `int (int, char**)` I couldn't resist pulling it all back in and recursing on `main`.

Degolfed somewhat for viewing pleasure:

```c
f;char*l,*u;                                                // Declare some storage. f is a counter used to only run the setup code on the original call to main. l gets assigned to be a pointer to the list of badges held. u is used as a buffer to track which badges are currently still available to be used.
main(n,x)char**x;{                                          // Typical golfed main declaration.
       if(f++){                                             // Only run the code in the if statement on subsequent calls to main (as a global f defaults to being initialized to 0).
               if(n){                                       // Catch the recursion base case (if n == 0 there are no stations left to pass).
                       for(int i=0;l[i];i++){               // Iterate over the badges we have available. i needs to be declared here since each recursive call needs to iterate over badges separately.
                               if(u[i]&&index(*x,l[i])){   // If the badge is available to be used (the entry in u for the badge is nonzero), and the badge is accepted by the next station...
                                       u[i]=0;              // Mark the badge as unavailable for the recursive call
                                       u[i]=main(n-1,x+1); // Recursively call main with the current station removed. If a sequence passing all stations is found the program exits immediately, so if main returns on an inner call it will always return 1; by assigning this into u we mark the badge as available again afterwards if we backtrack out of this call to continue searching.
                               }
                       }
                       return 1;                            // If we went over all our badges and couldn't get through this station, we need to backtrack the search so return 0 and continue.
               }
               exit(1);                                     // If there are no stations left we passed through all of them so immediately exit with code 1.
       }
       u=strdup(l=x[1]);                                    // Initialize storage for u. Initially I used calloc here, but since the needed length of u is the length of the list of badges held, strdup gets the job done while saving on bytecount (Just with the parity of the usage checks inverted since strdup means all the entries we care about are initialized to nonzero values).
       main(n-2,x+2);                                       // Make the first recursive call, with our new args starting at the first station's accepted badge list.
}                                                           // If we made it to the end without exiting the program, main will default to returning 0 since no return call was specified.
```

Comment: I hoped for a C solution! Great job. I would have never dared to call main() recursively :o

Comment: The switch to the ternary operator introduces a bug since setting `u[i]` to 0 is removed in order to have one statement. Consider the input `abcd`, `ac`, `def`, `cd`, `a`; it incorrectly indicates you can pass even though this would require using badge `a` twice.

Comment: [162 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7NCsMgEIRfpbkUNRvQHCuSBwk5pP6kC6ktNoIQ8uxW015mh293ltHdonXOTurHHNgKLMrnjJ54SID0hCzJHR1xbUt39woEVeMHm3AjggK/cbmOOEks61jM9Yre2ERYgsrpUKHicI7m97sTkFpBSzTYLQZ/4fKI6rMFE99kVWkUE/3X6Ppy2lN55JznuzZVsrEuV6@XLw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```python
f=lambda b,r:b==""or any(B in r[0]and f(b[:i]+b[i+1:],r[1:])for i,B in enumerate(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHPasQgEMbveYohPZiwFlp6C6SHHvoEvYkHjUoDu24ycemmIc@ezmS3f1JYwY8Z/X4qn92Y3o/xaVlCvTcH6wxYiZWt6zw/Ipg4Fi/QRkD1oE10EAqrqlbvrGp3j5WWqEjLQNZWrkYfTwePJvnCluWS/JAGqEFlShjrhATgohFSOB9IbeOEhs3QEu7gDU@eGWOY@YGM86yWWH2bCd9ME1Zmvef/NRfm1ewHhs7j58fldeeR7KvwClf6FtT1OCSi1oq82HesNHn5uq23r9swf2zyekbXswj9y@gs43w5Sg54jbTKgP4JkKLlnroO25iKkE92ljDhDPfPMNFvSSznvFy@AA) Golfed 1 byte by switching to an explicit enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>69</s>  68 bytes

Takes input as `(b)(a)`, where \$b[\:]\$ are the collector badges as a list of sets and \$a[\:]\$ is our list of badges.

```javascript
b=>g=a=>1/a||a.some((v,i)=>b[a.length-1].has(v)*g(a.filter(_=>i--)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNa8MwDIbv/RXvzfaWePS64YwdNhgb7LBjCENJ7TQjTVLb6xdlf71TSvdFwZZeiUcSvO@0olD5Zohp18/swZlDabLakMmmV7Tfkw79wkq5ShplsjIn3dqujvN0Wug5BblSF7Uk7Zo2Wi/fTNakqVLqcJNPgByCymomkmPGzDpwiarmTvQfFkVyooi@IZpZUGndOeKOSOUY4TVcOGrDL7DZ7tYjsdmC327N8YwZlj7EEWIBvxzgESK@u//u/UVPzBj4Y/hhJ8VEu97fUzWXMqcEZQJvQ6FgMlR9F/rW6rZnh3AJgVxwKkdZ4DPjLR4GTpY6DG0TpYBQekED0zze2TVebZTEdspca02FOk6Y8QRuIeTLkxK4ZvFw9/isBNv@BQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
b =>                       // b[] = collector badges as a list of sets
  g = a =>                 // g is a recursive function taking our list of badges
    1 / a ||               // yield +Infinity if a[] is empty
    a.some((v, i) =>       // otherwise, for each badge v at position i in a[]:
      b[a.length - 1]      //   test whether the collector at index a.length - 1
      .has(v) *            //   accepts the badge v
      g(                   //   multiply by the result of a recursive call where:
        a.filter(_ => i--) //     the i-th badge is removed from a[]
      )                    //   end of recursive call
    )                      // end of some()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
Ｓθ⊞υθＦθ«Ｓι≔υη≔⟦⟧υＦηＦΦκ№ιλ⊞υΦκ¬⁼λμ»¿υ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU27DsIwDJybr/DoSGFg7oQQSCwIiRExVBVtIkLSPMyC@PbgVELt4LPPd/b1uou972wpJzdRvuZo3IhBtuJCSSMpqPPgI/ASPqJZ2wxLzS4lM7rq1Ct6uyugyudTLWHuR2PzI@JTwd6Ty2gUWCkl/LMW/ewzHgJ1NqFV8GITP/sKMwAS@zk@41a2pUwhpiwWrMAlprJ52x8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs `-` if you can challenge the Elite Four. Explanation:

```
Ｓθ
```

Read the badges.

```
⊞υθ
```

Start with a single entry with all badges remaining.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over each guard.

```
Ｓι
```

Input the badges he accepts.

```
≔υη≔⟦⟧υＦη
```

Save the list of badges remaining so that we can clear it and still loop over the list.

```
ＦΦκ№ιλ
```

See whether this guard will accept any of these badges.

```
⊞υΦκ¬⁼λμ
```

If so then push the possible sets of remaining badges to the list. (If e.g. two guards both accept the same two badges then this could create duplicates depending on which badge you give to which guard but this does not affect the final result.)

```
»¿υ¹
```

If it was possible to give all the guards a badge then print a `-`.

Comment: @Arnauld Usually I remember to paste in the succinct byte count, yes...

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lpa`, <s>86</s> 79 bytes

```perl
$"="}{";@a=<>;chomp@a;map{$b=$F[0];$\|=!grep!$_,map$b=~s/$_//,/./g}glob"{@a}"}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxDsIgFEDR3b8oeSMtOHRCDJObX6CmebQETai8tG6Iny5il7Pc5JJbQl8KMM1yYsqgPhzVeI8zGVQzUgKr4XSRNwXXt2784qiBgddSw2cVMAjBRSd89iFalgzmOioFueXT7u@46Tanb6TXIz7X0p77Tu5laQPhDw)

First line of input is the badges you hold.  Subsequent lines are the ones needed.  On each line, badges are comma separated.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 40 bytes

```perl6
{@^a.permutations.map(*Z∈@^b).max.min}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBCsIwEEX3nmJAMCqlSzciuPIEriwVUk1UsBrTiq3ivuf0IjWTNnXEii7yO3mTvAlVQu9HZZxDT8IEytt0yX0ldHxOebo7HhI/5qo/XDyKYrqMBmaX@fHucC/HnU7Cc5D9gHHmscislVlrFnoBRWZroMeEWdLu6FEIsAS2YWE4GEMX5vqcbnOqBhdODGgAq4YarDEEAVEFTMifZknMKwdeZlu7iZVqxveJeKkybOYYV4xL5aupvU7r5gzhrVqFzROGxkgw0spNW1akG6AcsJ/mEnz1tf6dP2fTVtuED0pBXb89oHwC)

### Explanation

Basic approach is to work out every possible combination of our collectors badges against the other collectors badges and see if any combination is possible.

`@^a.permutations` computes all permutations of the list of your badges `[abcd] -> [[abcd],[abdc]...]`

`.map(*Z∈@^b)` For each of these permutations, zip each element of the resulting list (`*Z`) with whether each item is present in the corresponding other badge collector's badges (`@^b`).  `[abcd],[[abc][def][bcd][cg]] -> ((True False True False) (True False True True) ...)`

`.max` Return the highest element in the list, i.e. the one with the most Trues.

`.min` Return the lowest element in this list, i.e. true if all the elements are true, else false.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:any(all(map(str.count,b,c))for c in permutations(a))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddDNasQgEAfw@z7FQA/RIr30ttBrn6C3XQ8To1TwK2ropi@fOjZtdwsb8M8wmZ@Kaa3vMTxv5uW8OfTjhIBiPGJYGTrHPCZWan5ScQlVjEJxbmIGBTZA0tkvFauNoTDk/GBy9GCrzjVGV8D6FHN93Ai0PYmcDqcBRzUNAqBXgxgmbVpSU8L1JwU8wFteNBlEIr8GJ005NirvG/NjlOmmH/PvlN28oiuELuvnx/flLmsb70EdquQ9lOZcalO9arN5TpRtUXv/LW9vd2OuxsS@R5opBvln5BFStqEyw9prcr59AQ)

*-7 bytes thanks to xnor*

Comment: It looks like you can use `str.count` in place of  `str.__contains__`.